# Is it possible to add a minimum limit to a progress element in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I have created a Progress nativescript element. And i need to check if i can add a minimum value or different starting position?

```
var progress = new Progress();
progress.maxValue = 100;
progress.value = 20;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the native APIs for the native element that stands behind the NativeScript's Progress and set the min value (if such API is available).

For example, here is how you can achieve that on **Android** while using **Angular** (full demo [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=S3bWIV))

HTML  (my.component.html)

```
<Progress (loaded)="onProgressLoaded($event)"></Progress>
```

TypeScript (my.component.ts)

```
onProgressLoaded(args: EventData) {
    let progresBar = args.object as Progress;
    progresBar.value = 20;

    let nativeElement = progresBar.nativeView;

    if (isAndroid) {
        // on Android nativeElement is https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar

        nativeElement.setMin(19);
        nativeElement.setMax(50);
    }
}
```

The same can be done in NativeScript Core - .e.g here is an example for NativeScript + TypeScript core project.

XML

```
<Progress loaded="onProgressLoaded"></Progress>
```

TypeScript

```
export function onProgressLoaded(args: EventData) {
    let progresBar = args.object as Progress;
    progresBar.value = 20;

    let nativeElement = progresBar.nativeView;

    if (isAndroid) {
        // on Android nativeElement is https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar

        nativeElement.setMin(19);
        nativeElement.setMax(50);
    }
}
```